# How to implement generic fields from abstract class?

Tags: java, generics

I have an abstract class that has one field whose type can vary between its subclassses.  For example:

```
public abstract class ABCModel {
    protected String foo;
    protected String bar;
    protected ? baz;
}
```

In my implementations, `baz` may be an Int or a Float.  For example:

```
public class ModelFoo {
     protected Int baz;
}

public class Modelbar {
     protected Float baz;
}
```

First, let me ask if this is a valid/accepted design pattern in Java?  I've chosen this pattern because I want to abstract-away most of the tedious boilerplate in the shared methods.

Depending on how I implement it, I get variations of this error:

```
incompatible types: CAP#1 cannot be converted to BidAsk
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
```

This leads me to believe I'm doing something wrong.

The example I posted is a bit trivial compared to my actual code, in which this generic is buried in a nested hashtable.  I'm trying to decide if what I'm doing is a smart design in Java or not before getting too invested.

I've tried searching for this, but probably am not articulating the terminology correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: At a glance, this should be `class ABCModel<T>`, `class ModelFoo extends ABCModel<Integer>`, `class ModelBar extends ABCModel<Float>`.

Comment: So you're saying that the "<T>" will be overwritten everywhere a T is specified?  IE all <T> references will become Ints or Floats, for example?

Comment: Approximately.  It's moderately more complicated than that, but yes, that's the idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are asking is the basic usage of generics:

```
public abstract class ABCModel<T> {
    private T baz;

    public T getBaz() { return baz; }

    public void setBaz(T baz) { this.baz = baz; }
}

public class IntModel extends ABCModel<Integer> { // baz is of type Integer   
}

public class FloatModel extends ABCModel<Float> { // baz is of type Float   
}

IntModel m1 = new IntModel();
Integer i = m1.getBaz();

FloatModel m2 = new FloatModel();
Float f = m2.getBaz();
```

Comment: Thanks you for example

Comment: You could just rely on autoboxing/unboxing when calling the getters

Comment: @flkes you won't be so sure after getting some NullPointerExceptions in production ;)

Comment: And if instead of an abstract class, I was programming to an interface with generic methods, the idea would be the same?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker welp,.. now I've gotta rethink how I handle primitives! :p

Comment: @AdamHughes you can declare field in abstract class, but in interface you have only methods, no fields. So not exactly the same, it will work only for methods.

Answer (score 2):

This is an accepted pattern, but you should be more specific about your generics :

```
public abstract class ABCModel<T extends Number> {
    protected String foo;
    protected String bar;
    protected T baz;

    public T getBaz() {
      return baz;
    }
}
```

After that you can extend your model :

```
public class ModelFoo extends ABCModel<Integer> {
     // No need to specify again baz.
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for example

Answer (score 1):

Fields cannot be overridden in Java. You can however use methods with generics.

```
public abstract class ABCModel<T> {
    public abstract T getBaz();
}
```

Then

```
public class ModelFoo extends ABCModel<Integer> {
    public Integer getBaz() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: So my protected variables aren't being inherited at all?

Comment: Correction, cannot be overridden

Comment: They can't be overridden, but they can certainly be inherited and made generic.

Comment: Thanks Steve.  So now that you've used methods in place of my fields, would my extending classes have to redefine the field baz each time?  That's fine, just wanted to make sure I understand?  In other words, wouldn't getBaz() need to access a private variable, int baz?